# AngularJS Parsing JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the 2 following JSON:

```
[
  "36Yhfdjrnbfkdjres984",
  "53673hifujhdjkhgk77",
  "3456duedhde84473"
]
```

and

```
[
   {"_id":"36Yhfdjrnbfkdjres984"},
   {"_id":"53673hifujhdjkhgk77"},
   {"_id":"3456duedhde84473"}
]
```

I need to parse both with 2 differents methods:

```
$scope.onClickItem = function(tag) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api1')
             .success(function (response) {
                    console.log("response ", response);
             })
             .error(function (response) {
                     console.log(response);
             });
};
```

In response, I can see corectly the right JSON I need to get the id for /api1 and /api2

Comment: im not sure what the question is..

Comment: in response, I can see the JSON (I have 1 method for each of them) but I would like to store the id in an array.

Comment: these are separate responses. I just put 1 method here for the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the Id's to an array..

Create the Array object :

```
$scope.IdArray = [];
```

Then when you run through your function you can push the id into this.

```
$scope.onClickItem = function(tag) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api1')
                        .success(function (response) {
                            console.log("response ", response);
                            $scope.IdArray.push(response._id);
                        })
                        .error(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });
    };
```

Might be nicer to push an object into the array so something along the lines :

```
var idObj = {"ID", response._id};
$scope.IdArray.push(idObj);
```

But its all up to you and how you want to work with it.

Then you can do what you like with the ID array.

Comment: thanks but I already tried and I have undefined for response._id

Comment: well then your response does not have an id :) I suspect you will need `response.$each(function(singleItem){$scope.IdArray.push(singleIte._Id);});`